# What's the difference between "_main" and "main" in GNU Assembly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, gnu

I've just started to learn Assembly all by my own
my first step is to writing a Assembly code that returns '10' and check it with `$echo $?`

```
.global _main

_main:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        movl $10, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

this is my first version of code named 'ass.s',
and somehow when I compile with `gcc ass.s` 
it keeps returning error followed by
**/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to` main'**

when I fixed code to

```
.global main

main:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        movl $10, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

it worked well.

The only difference between those two code is `_main` and `main`
Can anyone explain why `_main` occur error?

Comment: _ is part of the symbol name. Just as if it were Xmain. It’s a different symbol.

Comment: but how become symbol occurs an error?

Comment: @prl: Right, but GNU/Linux does *not* prepend `_` to C names.  That's why `_main` doesn't work on Linux, but would be necessary on MacOS.